# Perform method of action chains does not work

Tags: python, selenium

I have a case where I need to drag and drop an element using Selenium webdriver and Python.

I tried using the `ActionChains` class of the Selenium, the code somewhat looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

source = ("//span[text()='user1']", Selector.XPATH)
target = ("//span[text()='user2']", Selector.XPATH)
acs = ActionChains(webdriver_api)
change = acs.drag_and_drop(source, target)
change.perform()
```

The error I am getting is:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 201, in <lambda>
self._driver.execute(Command.MOVE_TO, {'element': to_element.id}))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `source` and `target` need to be `WebElement` instances:

```
source = webdriver_api.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='user1']")
target = webdriver_api.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='user2']")

acs = ActionChains(webdriver_api)
change = acs.drag_and_drop(source, target)
change.perform()
```